# How to show that $B(x(t))$ can never become positive?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider a dynamical system with
>
> $$\dot{x} = f(x, t), \qquad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty)$$
>
> with $f$ being a locally Lipschitz continuous vector field. Next, let $X_0$ be the set of initial states and let $U$ be the set of unsafe states. We define $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $B$ is differentiable, $B(x) > 0, \forall x\in U,$ $B(x) \leq 0, \forall x\in X_0$ and $$B(x)=0\implies \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}(x)f(x,t) \leq 0$$
>
> Show that if we start from $X_0$ then it is impossible to reach $U$ if the function $B$ exists for the aforementioned dynamical system.

#### My attempt

Let $x(t)$ be any system trajectory that starts from $x_0\in X_0.$ Then we know that $B(x(0)) = B(x_0)\leq 0.$ Now if we somehow reached the set $U$ then this would mean that at some time $t$, the value $B(x(t))>0$ which would in turn imply that for some time $t^{*},$ we have that $B(x(t^*))=0\implies \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}(x)f(x,t^{*}) \leq 0.$ Now I guess we can find a neighbourhood where $B(x)$ is increasing from $B(x_0)<0$ to become positive and in that neighbourhood we have that $\nabla B >0,$ but I am not sure how to use the last condition to arrive at a contradiction. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $B$ known as a "barrier function"? Are you acquainted with Stephen Prajna's work?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, it is indeed. I read the paper and the proof there is not very clear to me.

Comment: If you have a solution $\gamma(t)$, can you compute derivative $\frac{d}{dt} \left ( B(\gamma(t))\right )$? How can it be expressed in terms of $\nabla B = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$ and $f(x, t)$?

Comment: Rewriting, $$B(x) = 0 \implies \left\langle \nabla_x B (x), f(x,t) \right\rangle \leq 0$$ Note that the gradient $\nabla_x B (x)$ at the hypersurface defined by $B(x)=0$ is orthogonal to the hypersurface and "points away" from $X_0$. Hence, $$\left\langle \nabla_x B (x), f(x,t) \right\rangle \leq 0$$ means that the vector field $f$ evaluated at the hypersurface defined by $B (x) = 0$ always points "inwards". Starting in $X_0$, one cannot "escape" from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x(t)$ be a solution to 
$$\tag{1}
\dot x=f(t,x)
$$
such that $B(x(t_0))\le 0$ and $B(x(t_*))>0$ for some $t_*>t_0$. Consider the function
$V(t)= B(x(t))$. It is continiously differentible and, by the chain rule, its derivative along the trajectory
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=\left.\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x(t)}\frac{dx}{dt}=\left.\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x(t)}f(t,x).
$$
Since $V(t_0)\le0$ and $V(t_*)>0$, there is, by the intermediate value theorem,
at least one $t^*\in [t_0,t_*)$ such that $V(t^*)=0$. If there are more than one such $t^*$ value, we take the last (maximum) value.

Hence, $t^*\in  [t_0,t_*)$ is such that $V(t^*)=0$ and $\forall t\in(t^*,t_*]\; V(t)\ne0$. This means (by the intermediate value theorem) that the sign of $V(t)$ remains the same in $(t^*,t_*]$. It is positive because $V(t_*)>0$, thus, $V(t)=B(x(t))$
increases at $t^*$:
[image]

But this implies 
$$
\left.\frac{dV}{dt}\right|_{t=t^*}=
\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}(x(t^*))f(t^*,x(t^*))
>0,
$$
which contradicts the assumptions of the theorem.